# Calculate correct start date for the below scenarios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have below condition.

```
Order.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date, end_date)
```

I want orders between **start_date** and **end_date**

But I want to write query for below scenarios.

1. If today's date is greater than 3rd July 2021 then I want the orders between 1st July 2021 to today's date.
2. If today's date is less than 3rd July 2021 then I want the orders from last month(1st June 2021) to 3rd July 2021.

How to calculate correct start date?

Comment: What are you having trouble with, it seems it should be straightforward with a simple `if` statement?

Comment: Is 3rd July 2021 hard coded value or in 2022 it should consider 3rd July 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start_date = (Date.today > Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month,3)) ? Date.today.at_beginning_of_month : Date.today.prev_month.at_beginning_of_month
```